# Using more than one table in a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new to PL/SQL. Can someone help me to solve the following scenario.
How to get the employee details like emp_id,full_name,department_id,total_salary
if we give Postal code as input parameter to the procedure. I know how to write a procedure to employee details from one table but here we have to use three tables.
Can any one help.
I am also providing the code I have used

```
 Create or Replace Procedure P1(postal_cd varchar2)
 as
     v_empid    number;
     v_name     varchar2(20);
     v_dept_Id  number(10);
     v_dept_nm  varchar2(10);
     v_hiredate date;
     v_sal      number;
 begin
     select e.emp_id
          , e.full_name||' '||e.last_name
          , e.department_id
          , d.department_name
          , e.hiredata
          , sum(e.sal) salary
       into v_empid
          , v_name
          , v_dept_id
          , v_dept_nm
          , v_hiredate
          , v_sal
       from employees   e
 inner join departments d
         on e.department_id = d.department_id
 inner join locations   l
         on d.location_id   = l.location.id
      where l.postal_code = postal_cd
          ;
 end;
```

Kindly let me know if the above query gives me the required result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not run it? and confirm it yourself. it seems correct.

Comment: There are issues in your code. For example the following statement is syntactically incorrect.  (on d.location_id   = l.location.id). It should be l.location_id. Also, you are doing sum(e.sal) without any group by. Please state your complete requirement. I would guess you want to display employee details belonging to a particular postal code. If that is the case then you need to go for a cursor based approach. Also, what do you mean by total sal. The sal column in the employees table should store the total sal for the employee. Do you want the total sal for the dept, loc or postal code?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This question was part of the exercises I am practicing.  @phonetic_man, Yes I have to display employee details belonging to a particular postal code. I am confused with total salary mentioned in in the exercise. It is only total salary per employee, so i think i don't have to aggregate and use group by.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display employee details belonging to a particular postal code the following code should help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(postal_cd VARCHAR2)
AS
     v_empid    NUMBER;
     v_name     VARCHAR2(20);
     v_dept_Id  NUMBER(10);
     v_dept_nm  VARCHAR2(10);
     v_hiredate DATE;
     v_sal      NUMBER;

     CURSOR cur_employee 
     IS
     SELECT e.emp_id, 
            e.full_name||' '||e.last_name AS emp_full_name, 
            e.department_id, 
            d.department_name,
            e.hiredata, 
            e.sal 
     INTO   v_empid, 
            v_name, 
            v_dept_id,
            v_dept_nm, 
            v_hiredate, 
            v_sal
     FROM   employees   e
     INNER  JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
     INNER  JOIN locations l ON d.location_id   = l.location_id
     WHERE  l.postal_code = postal_cd;


BEGIN

     FOR c_employee IN cur_employee
     LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_employee.emp_full_name || ' ' ||c_employee.department_id||' '||c_employee.department_name||' '||c_employee.hiredata ||' ' || c_employee.sal);
     END LOOP;

END;
```